# DB2 loginTimeout support

Tags: jdbc, db2

I am trying to set the db2 driver property loginTimeout.

My requirement is to set a timeout for any SQL execution in db2 for all my jdbc queries. If any query(Insert\Update\Delete) takes more than some time, say 2 seconds, the query should automatically timed out.

"db2://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/XXXXXXXX:loginTimeout=2;"

I am not sure, if iam configuring right. Please help.

I noticed the below in one of the website.
This property is not supported for IBM DB2 Driver for JDBC and SQLJ type 2   connectivity on DB2 for z/OS.

I guess the type 2 means the driver. I will check on that.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using the type 2 driver updating the client configuration might do the trick.

```
    db2 "update cli configuration for section common using querytimeoutinterval 0"
```